# How could the Electrokinesis of this race I’ve created be enhanced by Pyrokinesis?

Tags: science-fiction, xenobiology, super-powers, electricity

Ok, so in one of my stories, there’s an extraterrestrial species known as the Zareians, which possess a variety of superpowers. Much like humans, there are a variety of races of Zareians, each one with a slightly different assortment of powers, though all Zareians possess a base power set: Electrokinetic attacks.

This and the next 2, maybe more, questions I ask will be about how the Zareians’ other powers can be used to enhance the power of their Electrokinetic attacks in a significant manner. This one concerns the Pyrokinesis of the Zareian race known as the Fotea Makila.

**The Basics**

Now, the way that the Zareians generate their electricity is fairly wild. In their bodies, Zareians produce a chemical I’ve named Magnatallium. Magnatallium is a non radioactive, magnetic metal with a melting point of 2750°C. When heated to any temperature past 80°C, Magnatallium starts to produce an electric charge, which intensifies the hotter the metal gets:

- When heated past 150°C, Magnatallium will sporadically produce short-lived electric sparks, similar to a Tesla Coil, the frequency and duration of which increase with the metal’s temperature.
- When heated past 340°C, the electric sparks that start being produced by Magnatallium at 150°C will begin to heat up the metal further. At this point, realistically, Magnatallium would need to be cooled off fast, because the electric sparks will continually heat up the metal, eventually leading it to be extremely hazardous.
- When heated to its melting point, Magnatallium will become highly corrosive, with even a gallon of molten Magnatallium producing enough electricity to melt human flesh and muscle, without physical contact with the molten metal itself, in mere seconds, due solely to heat transfer from the electric bolts.

By producing Magnatallium in their bodies, the Zareians have a source of electricity in their body, which they store in a specialized organ designed to cool the Magnatallium when it is not in use. When needed, however, they can channel the Magnatallium into a system that, overall, works the same as the Circulatory system, pumping small bits of Magnatallium through a hot, watery fluid that heats the Magnatallium to ~200°C, allowing the metal to begin generating electricity without harming them. At this point, they will begin to use their abilities.

Their main attacks are a continuous/concentrated lightning bolt (which is fired from the aforementioned organ embedded in their hands), placing their hand on a conductive surface to channel electricity through it in waves, and discharging electricity through physical blows.

**Pyrokinesis**

As mentioned at the start, the question is how Pyrokinesis could significantly affect the power of these electrokinetic abilities. (For those who seem to be misinterpreting the question, Pyrokinesis is specifically fire manipulation, not just heat manipulation.) Either way, how could Pyrokinesis be combined with the electrokinetic attacks I mentioned (the lightning bolt and such) in a way that would significantly increase their power?

Answer (score 3):

You use pyrokinesis to heat up the magnatallium in your opponent's body, because as you stated

> When heated to its melting point, Magnatallium will become highly corrosive, with even a gallon of molten Magnatallium producing enough electricity to melt human flesh and muscle, without physical contact with the molten metal itself, in mere seconds

The more Magnatallium the opponent has put in circulation, the more exposed they are to such an attack.

Comment: And do it quickly, as per the OP's rules, your opponent would become stronger until the moment of instability.

Answer (score 1):

If we lower the hand-wavium, we need to recognize, that while Electrokinesis of your race sounds cool, it would in fact be extremely hard to utilize in any meaningful way. You have a mechanism to generate electric charge, that is valid. **Channeling electricity via contact, sounds reasonable**, and especially if you discharge while striking opponent, it could be very effective. (Discharging into conductive material, if grounded, will ground the charge rather than strike at someone.)
**The lightning bolts however, would be generally extremely unreliable**, **as** the electrons, will arch, over the path of least resistance to ground, and unless this path goes through enemy (which is very unlikely since they too will increase their charge making them repellent) **the electricity will just discharge somewhere** (most likely a grounded piece of electrical equipment).

**But** here comes **your pyromacer**, and suddenly the lightning-bolt aspect of your electrokinetics works as intended. Because now, instead of firing bolt of lightening at random and hoping it strikes true, pyromancer instead **uses pyrokinesis to create channel** of super heated air between your hand and your opponent (flame/plasma tunnel, if you want to make it more cinematic), **ionizing it**, **making** **it** an only **conductive path for your electric strike to follow**. Similarly it can be used defensively, to create more or less resistive path, to make sure the discharges of your opponent go somewhere else.

**TLDR: The pyrokinesis makes the lightning strike a viable form of attack, by creating an ionized trail of air for electricity to follow.**